What to do with seemingly anecdotal questions but actually because of lacking of terms?
We all expect sources to be indicative of general recurring observations, but what happens if the search result is overwhelmed with self-help articles that the anecdote became the only source "to be indicative of general recurring observations" OP can find? The root of the problem is that the OP lacking a decent vocabulary to describe what they want, and the consequence is that the question unavoidably becomes anecdote, and be closed. This would make frustration to the OP since they has hoped that this place is better than Google.
In other sites comments like "have a look at X", "it seems like you are talking about Y" can work, and the OP can continue their research. But I think it's discouraged on anecdotal questions since we want to avoid self-help topics. I think one have to be sensitive enough to be able to differentiate a self-help question and a question asking for terms and mechanisms that can cover personal observations, which doesn't contain any external sources because of lacking terms to effectively research.
While the burden of making it more objective is on the OP, I think it's better for both to just give a term to guide their research. Telling them to add any sources they find and explain why they don't meet their expectations can unstuck the block, but then isn't that ultimately personal observations have to be added to explain why the sources are not satisfying? Or when a source is add the observations wouldn't be personal anymore?

Related: What to do with questions asking for terms?

Can you add a recent example-post relating to your question? It's kind of a wordy post and an example does miracles sometimes.

can it not be recent? https://psychology.stackexchange.com/revisions/12699/1

The problem is that our site and especially our topics covered and our requirements for questions to be suitable here have changed over time, specially the last year or so. We have become more stringent. Therefore, linking old questions to support your claims may not be helpful.

the recent declination of the flag to reopen it suggests that at least with this question it's still relevant to this meta question

Yes, but that's your flag :) Meaning you find this relevant. To make this meta post relevant for everyone a more recent post would be more helpful. Up to you though.

@AliceD I see, thanks
